# htaccess redirect exits specific file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, default, not-exists

I store file like this

products/back.jpg

products/thumbnail.jpg


products/items/1/back.jpg

products/items/1/thumbnail.jpg


products/items/2/back.jpg

products/items/2/thumbnail.jpg


products/items/.../back.jpg

products/items/.../thumbnail.jpg

how to write htaccess with condition
if file not found redirect to root folder (products/)
but user see in old path name as same as they request?

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file in your document root, add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^products/.+/([^/\.]+)\.jpg$ /products/ [L]
```

If you want to try to load the same image then change the `RewriteRule` line to:

```
RewriteRule ^products/.+/([^/\.]+)\.jpg$ /products/$1.jpg [L]
```

If you want to put these rules in an htaccess file in your **/products/** directory, then remove the `products/` from the pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^.+/([^/\.]+)\.jpg$ /products/ [L]
```

Comment: error Object not found! on
Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4
i put .htaccess in document root